# How to safely secure plywood running board on ceiling joist

Tags: wiring, cables, cable-management

I am installing a plywood running board to hold multiple electrical NM cables on top of ceiling joist in my attic. I need a stronger way to secure them than drilling screws into the plywood and top edge of the ceiling joist because it's carrying electrical cables.

I am going to use a metal strap attached to the bottom of the plywood and secure the metal strap to the side (center) of the joist(s). This will protect the top and bottom load bearing edges of ceiling joist too. The joists are 2 x 6s.

So, which is the best way to secure the metal strap to the side of the joist? Use wood screws? Or, drill a small hole and use a metal bolt & nut to secure the metal strap, or use the same bolt & nut to secure another metal strap (or, the same metal strap) on other side of the joist?

Btw, I will be using Simpson Strong-Ties metal framing straps to secure the boards.

Also, what size and length of wood, or other type of screw(s) would be appropriate to adequately secure the strap to the side of 2 x 6 joist. And how far should the screw(s) penetrate into the side of the joist? All the way through, or halfway?

Always

Comment: Why do you need so much to just hold some wires? Typically cables are just stapled to joists.

Comment: You are way overthinking this. Decent construction screws have pullout strengths of nearly 1000 lbs each, just using two of them would hold a piece of plywood with enough rigidity you could stand on it. Compared to the weight of the joists, the cables weigh almost nothing. This metal strap business is totally unnecessary.

Comment: @longneck ,  in some jurisdictions the wire must be supported while running across the top of joists. Usually it is a 2X4 secured to the top of the joists. I figure the officials must be concerned about somebody stepping on the open span with a wire there. With blown in insulation prevalent these days, I could see that happening. It is required in WA state.

Comment: The running board(s) needs to be secured enough to withstand extreme lateral and vertical forces because I live in earthquake country. Have you ever experienced an earthquake lasting for minutes? It's not a fun ride!

Comment: Also, to protect someone from stepping through, or polling on the wires while working up in the attic. Btw, I am doing a total rewire and the running board(s) will support all the electrical circuits in the house.

Comment: Stapled NM wires on top of the ceiling joist are a bad idea. Overtime, the staple will penetrate the cable insulation and cause shorts. It has happen many times while someone was working up in the attic which has driven me to using running board(s) to protect the cables and to avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: Furthermore, running stapled NM on top of joists becomes messy i.e. spaghetti wire running in every direction on top of the joist.

Comment: This approach is an organized and prudent way to protect the NM cables and safely provide the ability to add future circuits to the house when needed.

Comment: And also keeping the house from burning down after an earthquake when electrical shorts ignite leaking natural gas! Yeah, I may be over thinking this, but it's all driven from my real experience as a claims adjuster during the Northridge earthquake and seeing all the damage that happen.

Comment: Getting back to the question, my concern is protecting the joist when the shaking starts, or many earthquakes over time. Remember that the top and bottom edge of the joist is where the loads are supported. I don't want to damage the joists because I just assumed it's a don't care and just drive screws any where into the joists to secure the boards. When I assume, it usually comes back to bite, and cost me a lot of money to fix.

Comment: If the house is up to earthquake standards, then the plywood will probably not make much difference.  The main idea is to attach the plywood so it does come loose and not make the joists not have enough give.  Rubber straps or springs might work better than solid mounts.  Will probably be better to have builder with knowledge of earthquake building to check and give advice.

Comment: Conduit is way too expensive for number of cables I need to run.  All I am asking is what is right way to attach a metal strap to the side of a ceiling joist, so it doesn't compromise the load bearing properties of the joist. Also, using a running board is not a code issue per my local building department who will do the electrical inspection. To resolve this issue I am just going to use the industry practices of how to drill holes, and notches in flooring joist, so it does compromise the joist. Since I am rewiring the house, everything I do must meet the current 2020 NEC to pass inspection.

Answer (score 1):

> I need a stronger way to secure them than drilling screws into the
> plywood and top edge of the ceiling joist because it's carrying
> electrical cables.

No, you don't.

Go down one level and look at how your plywood subfloors are attached to the joists they are on - screws or nails, possibly glue, possibly not. You are running a narrow strip of very lightly loaded flooring.

Your fire concerns would be better addressed with AFCI breakers and/or replacing all the NM cabling with EMT or FMC conduit and THHN wiring. Alternatively MC-Lite cable. There's a reason that's standard in places like Chicago. It has an excellent track record.